For loop to open and access satellite netcdf data
I am using satellite data to look at light levels in the surface ocean. (any data from here works as I'm just trying to understand how to open and work with the data)
In the code below, I saved all the .nc files in a folder on my desktop then imported it all under files then started a loop to open the file.
Is there a way to 1) crop the data extent(-180, -176, -40, -36)  then 2) extract the lat, Lon and par values? Im guessing that there is multiple depths available, but I dont know how to check that.
 library(raster)

 setwd("/Users/AquaModis_PAR")

 nc.data<-list()
 files<-list.files(pattern = ".nc",full.names=TRUE)

 df=NULL

  for(i in seq_along(files)) {
    par[i] = brick(files[i], stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE, varname = "par") 
   }


To load and crop the data do something like this:
library(raster)

files <- list.files(pattern = ".nc", full.names=TRUE)

region <- extent(-180, -176, -40, -36)

data <- lapply(files, function(path) {
  # Load and crop.
  d <- brick(path, stopIfNotEqualSpaced = FALSE, varname = "chlor_a") |>
    crop(region)
  
  # Get raster values.
  values <- getValues(d)
  # Get coordinates.
  coords <- coordinates(d)
  
  cbind(coords, values) |>
    data.frame() |>
    setNames(c("lon", "lat", "value")) |>
      na.omit()
})

Look at the data from the first file:
> head(data[[1]])
         lon       lat      value
28 -178.8542 -36.02084 0.06653178
29 -178.8125 -36.02084 0.06850998
30 -178.7708 -36.02084 0.07330192
31 -178.7292 -36.02084 0.07878597
34 -178.6042 -36.02084 0.07993947
35 -178.5625 -36.02084 0.08084643

There are probably more elegant ways to extract the data to a data frame, but this does the job.
The na.omit() at the end is to drop records where the value is missing (there were quite a few in the data I looked at).
For completeness, these are the files I tested it on:
AQUA_MODIS.20030101.L3m.DAY.CHL.chlor_a.4km.nc
AQUA_MODIS.20030102.L3m.DAY.CHL.chlor_a.4km.nc
AQUA_MODIS.20030103.L3m.DAY.CHL.chlor_a.4km.nc


thank you that worked! I have 2 questions: 1) for head(data[[1]]), does that mean it just takes the 1st layer (i.e., surface value)? how do I know how many depths/layers there are? and 2)is there a way to add the time as well? Im not sure it's in the files, because when I used nc_open I get 4 dimensions, lat, Lon, rib and eightbitcolour. If you notice, the files are saved by date. Is that something I have to add manually?

This is very inefficient as you throw away 99.9% of the data just read by immediately cropping it. No other option when you use raster I suppose...

MODIS AQUA L3m products have global coverage. You are interested in a small area of the world, (4 / 360) * (4 / 180) = 0.0247% and if you use raster::brick() you read 100% of the data to then throw away 99.9753%. Not very efficient.
With package ncdfCF you can do this much more efficiently. It'll also help you answer your other questions. But first some explanation.
MODIS data is distributed in NetCDF files. These files have attributes that you should inspect to interpret the data. Unfortunately, Swiss-Army-knife packages like raster (but also its successor terra and stars) don't provide (easy) access to those attributes so you'll need something more specifically tailored to NetCDF files. RNetCDF and ncdf4 do provide access to the attributes but not in a very user-friendly way. ncdfCF, on the other hand, gives you easy access:
> ds <- open_ncdf("AQUA_MODIS.20100101.L3m.DAY.PAR.par.4km.nc")
> ds[["par"]]
Variable: [0] par | Photosynthetically Available Radiation, R. Frouin

Dimensions:
 id axis name long_name length values                    
 1  X    lon  Longitude 8640   [-179.97917 ... 179.97917]
 0  Y    lat  Latitude  4320   [89.97916 ... -89.97917]  

Attributes:
 id name          type     length value                                             
  0 long_name     NC_CHAR   49    Photosynthetically Available Radiation, R. Frouin 
  1 scale_factor  NC_FLOAT   1    0.0020000000949949                                
  2 add_offset    NC_FLOAT   1    65.5                                              
  3 units         NC_CHAR   20    einstein m^-2 day^-1                              
  4 standard_name NC_CHAR   53    surface_downwelling_photosynthetic_photon_flux_...
  5 _FillValue    NC_SHORT   1    -32767                                            
  6 valid_min     NC_SHORT   1    -32750                                            
  7 valid_max     NC_SHORT   1    32250                                             
  8 reference     NC_CHAR  208    Frouin, R., Ligner, D.W., and Gautier, C., 1989...
  9 display_scale NC_CHAR    6    linear                                            
 10 display_min   NC_FLOAT   1    0                                                 
 11 display_max   NC_FLOAT   1    76.1999969482422   

This answers your question on the multiple depths. Variable "par" has dimensions lon and lat, so there is only 1 level. (Which makes sense: PAR is incident radiation (see the "standard_name" attribute), at sea level for this ocean product, attenuation through photosynthesis or absorption in the water is not considered.)
Since you want to loop over multiple files, you should differentiate by the dates of the individual files. Assuming you use "day" data, you can get the dates using sapply(strsplit(files, '.', fixed = T), function(d) d[2]). Note that a "date" is a flexible construct in MODIS data, the attributes for the dataset will show you that it extends over a period larger than 24 hours (attributes "time_coverage_start" and "time_coverage_end"). Taking the date from the file name is probably a wise choice.
Putting that together in a function you get:
read_par_array <- function(fn, extent) {
  out <- lapply(fn, function(f) {
    ds <- open_ncdf(f)
    subset(ds[["par"]], extent)
  })
  out <- abind(out, along = 3)
  dimnames(out)[[3]] <- sapply(strsplit(fn, '.', fixed = T), function(d) d[2])
  out
}

read_par_df <- function(fn, extent) {
  out <- lapply(fn, function(f) {
    ds <- open_ncdf(f)
    data <- subset(ds[["par"]], extent)
    as.data.frame(data)
  })
  names(out) <- sapply(strsplit(fn, '.', fixed = T), function(d) d[2])
  out
}

And then you call it with your files and extent of interest:
> library(ncdfCF)
> library(abind)

> files <- list.files(pattern = ".nc$", full.names = TRUE)
> extent <- list(X = c(-180, -176), Y = c(-40, -36))

> par <- read_par_array(files, extent)

read_par_array() produces a 3-dim array with dimensions longitude, latitude and date. You need package abind for that.
> par[1:3, 1:3, ]
, , 20100101

           -36.02084 -36.0625 -36.10417
-179.97917        NA       NA        NA
-179.9375         NA       NA        NA
-179.89583        NA       NA        NA

, , 20100102

           -36.02084 -36.0625 -36.10417
-179.97917    66.924   67.634    68.238
-179.9375     67.118   68.226    68.530
-179.89583    67.770   68.330    68.716

, , 20100103

           -36.02084 -36.0625 -36.10417
-179.97917    39.712   45.216    47.190
-179.9375     38.406   39.846    42.994
-179.89583    37.066   33.886    39.686

, , 20100104

           -36.02084 -36.0625 -36.10417
-179.97917        NA       NA        NA
-179.9375         NA       NA        NA
-179.89583        NA       NA        NA

, , 20100105

           -36.02084 -36.0625 -36.10417
-179.97917    68.226   68.160    68.162
-179.9375     68.254   68.184    68.230
-179.89583    68.302   68.312    68.318

read_par_df() gives a list with 1 element per file. Each element is named after the date in the MODIS file name. Every list has 1 data.frame, with named latitudes in columns and longitudes in rows:
> names(par)
[1] "20100101" "20100102" "20100103" "20100104" "20100105"
> par[["20100102"]][1:3, 1:3]
           -36.02084 -36.0625 -36.10417
-179.97917    66.924   67.634    68.238
-179.9375     67.118   68.226    68.530
-179.89583    67.770   68.330    68.716

There are quite a few NAs in the data and I am going to guess that these are caused by cloud cover during the day: the algorithm is for clear-sky conditions only. Under cloudy conditions the amount of PAR at the sea surface is very much reduced so if you can live with that in your analyses then please go ahead. Otherwise, have a look at MCD18C2 products (5-minute granules, so a tad more effort involved...)
Disclaimer:  I am the developer of package ncdfCF. I also have a PhD from 2004 in computing PAR using MODIS data, I started my research weeks before MODIS Terra went up.
